# Will I face a problem if I have a different email ID for Android and Apple?

Tags: apple-id

I forgot the answers to my Apple ID security questions, and now, I cannot get my Apple ID back. So, I decided to use a new Apple ID for my brand new, **and very first**, iPhone.

Will I face a problem for having a different Email ID for Android, and one for Apple? Like, any app or say where I purchased a subscription that can be shared between Android and Apple devices ?

Answer (score 9):

I think it's worth explaining a point here that might be getting lost.

Any app you purchased from the Google Play store, you'll need to purchase again on the Apple App Store.  There's no sharing there - they're just totally different.

However, apps where you pay the app maker directly, and not the App Store, will have some other account - one directly with the app developer.  For example, Disney Plus, or Netflix, or Amazon Prime; all of those, you may have a separate account with the app developer.  In those cases, the separate account is with whatever email you want it to be with - it doesn't have to be the same as that of the App Store email.  You would have to log in with that service again with whatever that email is - but it would work fine.

Please note that, at the present, not very many apps work this way; for the most part, on iOS, you buy from Apple only.  The primary exception is "reader" apps, where you buy media somewhere else and then stream or download it; hence my mention of video apps earlier.  There are a few other apps that do work this way, but they're very rare.  This may change soon, due to various lawsuits and laws, but hasn't yet.

For clarity: Netflix, Amazon Prime, and Spotify all work like reader/streaming apps. You have a subscription with them, and you can use it on both iPhone and android.

Comment: So, by any chance, do you mean that if I buy Netflix or Prime subscription, even Spotify (the three of which I have right now in Android) via an Apple product, I cant use them on Android? Because although I bought an iphone, I still have an Android tablet for entertainment and study stuff.

Comment: @Skumar that's because of the appstore policies that drain part of the proceeds from what you buy through the app to the appstore. Whether that means your account can't be used on the other platform would depend on the app.

Comment: @Skumar The three that you have listed only take direct payments (they don't have subscriptions via Apple App Store or Google Play, unless you're still on Netflix's or Spotify's older subscriptions which do still offer in-app payments, or get Prime Video through your carrier), so you'll have no issues accessing them on any device you wish.

Comment: You can't "buy" Netflix and Amazon Prime on an Apple device. You go to the website, you buy it there, and you can use it anywhere. They'll want a username and password, you will have to enter that on your Netflix or Prime app on the Apple device. Not related to your Apple ID in any way.

Comment: @Skumar Most subscriptions that let you watch or listen to media work this way - you can watch on any device as you have a subscription with them. (Even ones that do let you buy on the App Store - Disney and Paramount - still have you sign up an account with them and sync to it, to let you do this).  But these are for the most part the only apps that will work that way.

Answer (score 3):

You are unlikely to have a problem with different email ids across different devices. I have owned both Apple and Android devices for several years, I have never come across a situation where an app/subscription was shared across both platforms. In fact I have had to buy new apps when I changed phones within the same platform (Android to newer Android) because the creators of the app could not/were not interested in catering for people upgrading phones. Effectively with an Apple phone and a separate Android phone you have two identities-one for each platform.

For the Android devices I've owned I've always gone with a new email address each time and just appended the device name so I know which device an email is related to e.g. joebloggsnote4@domain.com, joebloggsnote8@domain.com, ...

Comment: Umm, how do you manage to get your contacts ?

Comment: @Skumar both Apple and Android have an option to import contacts from each other. For example on your iPhone you can add a Google account and it will happily use those contacts and show its email.

Comment: @Skumar I use an email provider who supplies domains which redirect to a known account. For example say for example one of the mail domains made available is "abc.com" they also provide the capability to create a subdomain which points to my mailbox e.g. "mymail.abc.com". Then mail sent to devicename@mymail.abc.com ends up in the one mailbox regardless of the label "devicename". Couple this with folders in the mailbox to keep things tidy.

Answer (score 1):

If you changed your Apple Id, you can no longer access apps / subscriptions purchased with your old Apple Id. So if you have bought any apps, music or video from the App Store or Itunes Store, you will no longer have access to it. In such a case, it is best to contact Apple support and ask them to reset your password.

As for sharing some paid service on both Apple and Android, usually you won't have any issues. Unless they send you some important information though, to your old email id - like some verification link when you sign-in to a new device. So it is best to contact customer support of the company offering the service / subscription and request them to update and change your email id to something you still have access to.

Comment: They are not allowing that. Also, I didnt have anything in that old id. I had created it, just because I thought I would buy an iPad back in the day, but I didnt. Now that I have bought an iPhone, I wanted to see if I would come across any problem. So, basically, I waited for 2 days without setting up my device, lol

Comment: Then don't worry about the old Apple Id if you didn't use it with Apple or any other service. But do remember that all purchases made on Apple is tied to your Apple Id, and not your iPhone or iPad. So provide a phone number + email in your Apple Id account, and enable 2 factor authentication so that you don't lose access to that account.